# How to stop require.js one file optimization from minimizing some paths?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm using `r.js` to create a one file script for my application using the following command:

```
r.js -o ./scripts/require.build.json baseUrl=public/js/ name=main out=main.min.js
```

were require.build.json has the following options:

```
{
    "paths": {
        "jquery": "plugins/jquery.1.8.2.min",
        "underscore": "plugins/underscore.1.4.2.min",
        "backbone": "plugins/backbone.0.9.2.min"
    },
    "shim": {
        "backbone": {
            "deps": ["jquery", "underscore"],
            "exports": "Backbone"
        },
        "underscore": {
            "exports": "_"
        }
    }
}
```

my `main` file is just a simple test case:

```
/*jslint browser: true */
/*global define: false*/
define(function (require) {
    "use strict";

    var $ = require("jquery"),
        Backbone = require("backbone");

    window.console.log($);
    window.console.log(Backbone);
});
```

I wonder, how can I avoid `r.js` from minifying the **already minified** files of my dependencies (jQuery, Underscore and Backbone) to save time?

Comment: Doesn't directly answer your question, but why not use the unminified versions? Makes debugging easier in development and then let r.js handle all the libs and modules for production.

Comment: @SimonSmith This configuration is for compressing all files to one for production. By indicating the minified versions does `require.js` detect they are already minified?

Comment: It will minify everything, uncompressed or not. The way I use require is to have all my modules and js libs (jQuery etc) in their uncompressed state whilst in development. Then I let r.js compress them, whether it's all into one file or multiple ones. Makes life easier for debugging and such with uncompressed libs.

Comment: @SimonSmith I understand, I wanted to save time on the build process by avoiding to compress already compressed files.